# Sidebar widgets are looping out of the sidebar wrapper

Tags: sidebar

If there is no post and sometimes, the sidebar widgets are looping out of the sidebar wrapper.

sidebar.php

```
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <?php if(!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar')) : endif; ?>
    </aside>
</div>
```

output:
[image: This kind of]

Thanks so much.

Comment: How about `.sidebar * {max-width:100%;}`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment but, the problem is not in style, sidebar widgets are looping out of the sidebar wrapper.

Comment: If not a CSS issue, you might want to post a raw html code of all your sidebar.

Comment: Already I post the sidebar.php codes and output.

Comment: If content is overflowing the container, then this is an HTML/CSS issue so as @Abhik suggested, you should also post your HTML structure.

Comment: @jami0821 Thank you for your come help, The problem is not due to Front end.

Comment: The code (sidebar.php) does not output correctly.

Comment: Actually I wrote the wrong title.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output *with* a post?

Comment: The problem is actually exactly: If there is no post, sidebar widgets are being displayed on the screen except the sidebar wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The widgets that contain the loop in the sidebar are had caused the problem.

- The problem is solved.

Comment: Please explain how you did solve your issue, It will helpful for future viewers of this post. Right now your are just telling us that you solved your problem. Also don't forget to accept your own answer after 2 days of posting.